# apply machine learning to analysis mixed language

Tags: machine-learning

I am a starter of machine learning and I wonder if it's possible to apply machine learning to the following case.

Image I am passing a mixed language string (english + anything else) to the machine learning library, and I expect the library tells me if this string has been fully translated from english to the target language or not. For example

Example 1:

- input:
  "i amor iphone" #(i love iphone in spanish)
- expected result:
  Does not need future translation as 'iPhone' is a branding name

Example 2:

- input:

  "请upload您的文件" # (please upload your file in Chinese)
- expected result:

  Needs future translation (to Chinese) as "upload" is an action which should be translated.

If machine learning could apply to this, then how should I pick the dimension of the input string and which algorithm should I pick (logistic regression or neural network? )

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Natural language processing is a large and diverse field. You can think about your example a number of ways.

The first is character sets and symbol encoding. Most non-romance languages will have characters outside the standard 26 letter alphabet. If you see characters from inside and outside the core character ranges for a language, it works around needing a lot of dictionaries.

The second is to look at a set of examples or words in a certain language and use Naive Bayes classification to associate words with languages in some training set.

You may be able to go further doing stem detection and more but I haven't studied them well enough.  Consider posting on Crossvalidated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am thinking about non-romance language detection. Basically first step is to extract all the English characters from the given string, if there's no english string, no future work needed, otherwise, analysis the speech of the english string (verb, noun, etc). Then there may be 2 cases : if the english string is verb, highly likely that it needs future translation, else if it's noun, unless it's branding name, then future translation might be needed.

Comment: Will this be a practical approach?